# How can I recv() data until specific time in python?

Tags: python, sockets

in python socket programming, settimeout() supports nonblocking recv operation. however, non blocking socket will return immediately once data arrives in time.

I want my socket to be blocked for certain amount of time regardless data comes or not. and recv all the incomming data until that amount of time.

is there some simple and easy way to implement this without using threads?

thank you in advanced

Comment: Just wait this specific amount of time before calling any receive function?

Comment: @alk, please make this into an answer.